# Change month to letter in VBA

Tags: vba

Hello I have variable with current date and I want to change the month of the date to the name of the month or any letter.

My variable has value: `19.10.2020`

In short, I want to change 10 to oct or, for example, AA

How can i do it in VBA?

Comment: Have you tried using `Format$`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: No i don't use Format$ but how can I use it?

Comment: `Format$("19-10-2020", "mmm")` appears to work for me. Seems to need - instead of . between the numbers though

Comment: Format has lots of options, i included a link to the documentation for you so that you can select which option you wanted.

Comment: Date separator is based on windows regional settings so `Format$("19.10.2020", "mmm")` will probably work for you.

Comment: I have variable as type string, name variable: Date

Comment: `Format$(Date, "mmm")`

Comment: If the variable is already a string, then you have to convert it to an actual date first, before you can use `format` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions

Answer (score 0):

Whenever having a formatting question, a good option is to see what the VBA Excel macro recorder does, when the task is carried out.

In this case, formatting the cells like this:
[image]

will generate the following code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"
    Range("G8").Select
End Sub
```

Thus, `Range("A1").NumberFormat = "[$-409]d-mmm-yy;@"` would be a working answer.

Comment: i think his issue is that it's currently a string that looks like a date... based in the above comments

Answer (score 0):

You can write a conversion function. 
For example:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox (GetNewMonth("19.10.2020"))
End Sub


Private Function GetNewMonth(ByVal datestring As String) As String
Dim splitted() As String
splitted = Split(datestring, ".")
Dim day As String
Dim month As String
Dim year As String

day = splitted(0)
month = splitted(1)
year = splitted(2)

GetNewMonth = day & " " & ConvertMonthNumToLetter(CInt(month)) & " " & year

End Function

Private Function ConvertMonthNumToLetter(ByVal monthnum As Integer)
    Select Case monthnum
        Case 1
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "JAN"
        Case 2
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "FEB"
        Case 3
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "MAR"
        Case 4
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "APR"
        Case 5
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "MAI"
        Case 6
         ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "JUN"
        Case 7
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "JUL"
        Case 8
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "AUG"
        Case 9
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "SEP"
        Case 10
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "OCT"
        Case 11
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "NOV"
        Case Else
        ConvertMonthNumToLetter = "DEC"
    End Select
       
End Function
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
19 OCT 2020
```

Comment: What about `Format()` function.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert to a string that can be read as a date, then format this - like:

```
=Format(Replace("AA", ".", "/"), "d.mmm.yyyy")

-> 10.Okt.2020
```